# Steps to setup Secor for a Kafa Topic

Tags: pinterest

I am very new to Pinterest Secor and I am trying to set it up for my local Kafka topic. I tried reading the official GitHub documentation but it does not explain the complete steps to be followed and which fields should be modified in the config files and what do they mean. It would be great if someone can direct me to a useful link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to set-up Secor, as per the official Secor documentation.
[Secor doc link](https://github.com/pinterest/secor/blob/master/README.md)

Some major steps are:-

- 1.To create a Java class to define your partitions. These partitions
     are the S3 or Azure paths/folder structures where you would like to
     upload your data.

  2. In the config file -> https://github.com/pinterest/secor/blob/master/src/main/config/secor.prod.partition.properties
     Update the class name to your class name
  3. Set the kafka group name in the property secor.kafka.group
  4. Set the directory where you will keep the secor data temporarily before it is uploaded to S3/Azure-blob. update this
     property ->secor.local.path
  5. Update the base path of your S3 location. Update this property -> secor.s3.path
  6. set kafka host from where you want to consume data -> kafka.seed.broker.host
  7. set zookeeper ip and port that manages your kafka -> zookeeper.quorum
  8. set the time after which your file is uploaded to s3 -> secor.max.file.age.seconds